# Getting a turret to turn until facing a target direction?

Tags: math, vector, box2d, game-physics, trigonometry

I'm trying to get a turret to face an enemy, I have all the logic setup my problem is trigonometry.

Here's an illustration I've draw:

[image]
Here's the code I've got so far:

```
//Get the target degree (Is returned with a box2d world facing right, so make it face up)
        float targetDegree = (((currentLockedEnemy.getBody().getPosition().sub(getBody().getPosition()).angle() + 270f) % 360f));

        //Get the turret current facing degree.
        float currentTurretFacingDirection = (getBody().getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees) % 360f;
        //Because box2d can go negative angles.
        if(currentTurretFacingDirection < 0f){
            currentTurretFacingDirection += 360f;
        }

        //Because it will go over 360 to 0. Make it within the 180 to -180 range. Fixes the skip
        if(currentTurretFacingDirection > 180f){
            currentTurretFacingDirection -= 360f;
        }
        if(targetDegree > 180f){
            targetDegree -= 360f;
        }

        //Subtract the current turret facing angle from the target.
        float rotationalOffset = targetDegree - currentTurretFacingDirection;


        //If it's greater than the accuracy turn towards the object.
        if(Math.abs(rotationalOffset) > getAccuracy())
        {

            if(rotationalOffset > 0f)
            {
                this.revoluteJoint.setMotorSpeed(TURN_SPEED);
            }
            else
            {
                this.revoluteJoint.setMotorSpeed(-TURN_SPEED);
            }
        }
        else{
            this.revoluteJoint.setMotorSpeed(0f);
        }
```

My question is, how on earth do I get the turret to turn at the right angle?

FYI
I'm using Box2d with Libgdx and the language is JAVA.

Comment: what language/engine is this?

Comment: Box2d, Libgdx - JAVA.

Comment: Btw, `atan2` *can* work with negative coordinates

Comment: Still not sure how I'd use it. The first var is using atan2.

Comment: Are you trying to *face* the target, or are you trying to *turn towards* the target?

Comment: Both, turn until face?

Comment: Then you're doing it bass-ackwards. Translate the system until the turret is at the origin, rotate it to 0, and *then* use atan2. I'm sure there's a faster way of doing it than one step at a time, but this is the general procedure.

Comment: This might help: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/rotate-to-angle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should take the angle of the target relative to the turret, not the other way around. This can be fixed by swapping the position vectors in the subtraction.

Second, once you have the target angle, subtracting the turret's current angle will give you the rotation offset you need to apply. Then, use some modular arithmetic and a few `if`s to shift that offset between `-180` and `+180`. If the result is positive, you need to rotate one way. If it's negative, you need to rotate the other way. If the result is "close enough" to zero, then the turret is aiming "close enough" to the target ("close enough" depends on how accurate you need it to be).

Comment: I updated my code, still trying to get my head around the -180 to 180 range thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a different approach altogether.

Derive a line that passes through the turret, pointing in the direction the turret is facing, as the coefficients [a,b,c] in the line equation ax + by + c = 0.

Calculate the distance from the line to the target using the equation:
D = (a.tx + b.ty + c) / Sqrt( a^2 + b^2 )

If D is negative, turn the turret left, if it's positive, turn the turret right (or the other way around if that's the case). If D is 0, the turret is either facing the target or facing the opposite direction to the target.

Here's some pseudo code to show what I mean. I assume that there is some way to get a "forward vector" for the turret, i.e., a 2d vector that points in the direction that the turret is facing.

```
public static float calculate(float turretPositionX, float turretPositionY, 
            float turretForwardX, float turretForwardY, 
            float targetPositionX, float targetPositionY)
        {
            float a, b, c;
            a = turretForwardY;
            b = -turretForwardX;
            c = -(a * turretPositionX + b * turretPositionY);

            float d = (a * targetPositionX + b * targetPositionY + c) / (float)Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b);

            // if d is negative, turn one way, if it's positive, turn the other. 
            // if it's zero, you're either facing directly toward the target, or directly
            // away from it.
            return d;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's Sqrt a little expensive in a game loop? by ax + by + c = 0; do you mean: (a*x) + (b*y) + c. Programatically?

Comment: I mean vid the values [a,b,c] that represent the line. a and b should be  -y, x of the turrets forward vector, c can then be found by c = -(ax + by), where x and y are the coordinates of the turret. I wouldn't worry about sqrt being expensive in this day and age, unless it's shown to be a bottleneck with a profiler :)

Comment: Can you give me an example programmatically? I struggle with math concepts.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a code snippet - let me know if it's useful or not :)